# "apt-get source" for packages.ros.org?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where are the sources (*.orig.tar.gz, *.diff.gz, and *.dsc files) for the debs on packages.ros.org?

Specifically, how to make "apt-get source" do the right thing for packages from this repository?  Adding the obvious deb-src line to ros-latest.list doesn't seem to help (see below).  Poking around on the packages.ros.org http interface, it looks to me like the sources have not been uploaded.

Packages I care about include ROS dependencies like assimp, yaml-cpp, and eigen.  For example,

```
$ apt-cache policy libassimp2
libassimp2:
  Installed: 2.0.0.6-ubuntu1~lucid1
  Candidate: 2.0.0.6-ubuntu1~lucid1
  Version table:
 *** 2.0.0.6-ubuntu1~lucid1 0
      500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ lucid/main Packages
      100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list 
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu lucid main
$ apt-get source libassimp2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'assimp' as source package instead of 'libassimp2'
E: Unable to find a source package for assimp
$ sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu lucid main
deb-src http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu lucid main
$ sudo apt-get update
...
Ign http://packages.ros.org lucid/main Packages
Ign http://packages.ros.org lucid/main Sources
Hit http://packages.ros.org lucid/main Packages
Get:1 http://packages.ros.org lucid/main Sources [20B]
Fetched 20B in 1s (14B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
$ apt-get source libassimp2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'assimp' as source package instead of 'libassimp2'
E: Unable to find a source package for assimp
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12478/%22apt-get-source%22-for-packages.ros.org?/) by [martyvona](https://answers.ros.org/users/1586/martyvona/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-12-28

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just a follow-up; with the current package repository of ros.org (Sep 2014), you can obtain the source of the released packages by simply `apt-get source`. <s>No `deb-src` needed.</s> I documented it [here](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu#groovy.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-PostInstall.Obtain_source_code_of_the_installed_packages).

Update 12/10/2014) `deb-src` seems to be required. I updated the link above too.

**Edit with full instructions:**

You just need to explicitly specify deb-src entry in the apt sources:

For example update `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros_latest.list` as follows:

```
  deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main
+ deb-src http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main
```

This assumes precise substitute your applicable ubuntu distro.

```
$ apt-get source ros-hydro-laser-pipeline
```

This downloads from the server all the files in the released version of the package (i.e. things not installed in the installation rule (e.g. CMakeLists.txt) are also included).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2702/damjan/) on 2014-12-09**:
This does not seem to work for me. I'm running Hydro on 12.04, e.g., both

```
apt-get source ros-hydro-gmapping
```

and

```
apt-get source ros-hydro-slam-gmapping
```

return E: Unable to find a source package for ros-hydro-slam-gmapping.

Am I missing something?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-12-09**:
@damjan I've updated my post above.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-12-09**:
@130s that's not an appropriate place to put that information. Placing that at the end of the procedural instructions will distract/confuse beginner users as it's not necessary/useful for them to get started. It should be documented for power users, where I think this thread is pretty good.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-12-09**:
I would also highly recommend using rosinstall generator instead of apt-get source for fetching packages as you will get a version controlled source.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-12-09**:
I pulled the full content in here and promoted this answer. It's already the top search result for apt-get dsc ros https://www.google.com/search?q=apt-get+dsc+ros

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-12-09**:
@tfoote Very much agreed.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks the same for me.

This doesn't exactly fix your problem, but you can usually download the source code from each packages wiki entry and overlay the installed version with the sources by putting the local source directory to the front of the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-12-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martyvona](https://answers.ros.org/users/1586/martyvona/) on 2011-12-29**:
I want to rebuild the debs for a robot that runs an armel cpu and that may need custom patches in some cases.  The original "upstream" source is only part of that.  I also need the debian control files and especially the patchsets applied when the ros.org debs were built.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will find the source for all the ros released stacks in the release repository https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/stacks/

The existing infrastructure for 3rd party packages are quite ad hoc at the moment.  We are redesigning the system to make the whole process easier.

In the mean time you can find the stacks you are looking for in gitbuildpackage repos:

- Eigen is from debian upstream http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=debian-science/packages/eigen3.git;a=summary cloned at https://kforge.ros.org/rosrelease/eigen3debs
- yaml-cpp https://kforge.ros.org/rosrelease/yamlcppdebs
- assimp is pulled from launchpad [https://launchpad.net/~openrave/+archive/release](https://launchpad.net/%7Eopenrave/+archive/release)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1